# Using matlab to save a 100 text files to a one excel file but into different spread sheet?

Tags: excel, matlab, text

Hi 
I have a about 50 to 100 text file which i want to impot their data into à different spread sheet. 
All the files have two row text, Thord row began with numbers and text after it. The rest is like 1000 x 500 int. 
I want to do this in matlab.

Please, any suggestion????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MATALB under Windows, you can use COM automation to control Excel and create the necessary file.

Take a look at [xlswrite](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2855-xlswrite) in the Mathworks file exchange for an example.

The referenced code does not create a new Excel sheet, but can populate any existing sheet you create beforehand (in an existing workbook of course).

If `filename` is the file to open, the following code (based on xlswrite) may be helpful:

```
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
op = invoke(Excel.Workbooks, 'open', [pwd filesep filename]);
set(Excel, 'Visible', visible); % you may safely remove this
cell_update(sheetname, row, col, value)

function cell_update(sheetname, row, col, value)

    % Make the specified sheet active.
    try
        Sheets = Excel.ActiveWorkBook.Sheets;
        target_sheet = get(Sheets, 'Item', sheetname);
    catch
        % Error if the sheet doesn't exist.  It would be nice to create it, but
        % I'm too lazy.
        % The alternative to try/catch is to call xlsfinfo to see if the sheet exists, but
        % that's really slow.
        error(['Sheet ' sheetname ' does not exist!']);
    end;

    invoke(target_sheet, 'Activate');

    Activesheet = Excel.Activesheet;
    cellnum = [num2col(col) num2str(row)];
    ActivesheetRange = get(Activesheet,'Range', cellnum, cellnum);
    set(ActivesheetRange, 'Value', value);


end
```

Comment: Would you mind to explain à little bit more. I tryed to find  more info but i couldn't.

Comment: Try the above code with Matlab running on a Windows machine. Excel must be installed as well. The code starts an Excel process, opens an existing workbook (specified by the 'filename' variable that you need to set) and starts writing into specific cells on specific sheets by calling cell_update() with the desired sheetname, row and column and value to put in the cell.

Comment: Thx. I got an error message which says undefined command/function 'cell_update'.

Comment: The function cell_update is defined in the above answer. The "value" is whatever you want to put into the spreadsheet cell. You need to read the text file, iterating over the rows and columns and call cell_update() with the target sheet name, desired row and column and the value you want to put in the cell.

Comment: Hi again! I have another quastion :)  . If i want the the program to gå to a folder with uigetfile and open à text file as xls and save it ( this much i can do with your code ) but now when i open a second file as xls i want it to be opened in the last xls file but in the new work sheet . Do you have any ideas how i can do this????