# importing several text files into excel spreadsheet using matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, import, text-files, spreadsheet

I have several text files with 2 columns, containing only numbers which i would like to import into a single Excel spreadsheet (Excel 2016) using matlab. Reason for using matlab (R2014a) is because i later have scripts that process the data as well as its the only progaming language i am mildly familiar with.
I tried to use the following 
[Using matlab to save a 100 text files to a one excel file but into different spread sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802259/using-matlab-to-save-a-100-text-files-to-a-one-excel-file-but-into-different-spr)
but  i just couldnt understand anything as I am a newbie and this example I think is for making several excel files while I want only one. Thanks for the help! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a sample text file? Reason behind asking this is to know the spacing between 2 columns in text file.
Also, when you read the second text file, do you want the data in a new sheet in same workbook (or) same sheet in same workbook?
If same sheet in same workbook, do you want to put the data read from second text file under the data read from first text file?

Comment: 1) I would like the data to be in the same sheet and the same workbook 2) the data from 2nd text file should be next to data from 1st text file. So 1st text file data in col 1 and col 2 and 2nd data file in col 3 and col 4 and so on........ the link for an example file is at this link http://www.filedropper.com/an050me

Answer (score 0):

```
content = dir();
col = 1;
for i = 1:10
    if content(i).isdir ~= 1
        fileID = fopen('AN050ME.ASC');
        data = textscan(fileID, '%s %s');
        fclose(fileID);
        datum(:, col) = data{1};
        col = col + 1;
        datum(:, col) = data{2};
        col = col + 1;
        clear data;
    end
end

filename = 'Datum.xls';
sheet=1;
xlswrite(filename, datum, sheet, 'A1');
close all;
```

This is basic working algorithm, you need to further work on it to optimize it for speeed

Hints:
 1. pre-declare the size of datum, based of number of files.
 2. if all the files you have to read are of same extension, read only
    them through dir()

Good luck for fine tuning

Comment: Thank you very much. As i am a newbie i changed a bit of your initial code to something more familiar to me. I did get the Excel spreadsheet that I wanted but 1) I also get the commas into the Excel cells  which I would like to remove. I read something about using 'delimiter' in 'textscan' but i am not sure how to go about it. Also 2) is it possible to get the first row of the excel file as header which contains the name of the asci file? I always have trouble figuring this out.

Comment: ``all_files=dir('*.asc');
col=1;
for k=1:1:length(all_files);
filename=all_files(k).name;
fid=fopen(filename);
data = textscan(fid,'%s %s');
fclose(fid);
datum(:, col) = data{1};
col = col + 1;
datum(:, col) = data{2};
col = col + 1;
clear data;
end
filename = 'Datum.xls';
sheet=1;
xlswrite(filename, datum, sheet, 'A1');
close all;``

Comment: sparts = strread(desired_string, '%s', 'delimiter', ',');
sparts(0) will have the part of the string before comma

Comment: Answering your second question

datum(2:1002,:) = datum(1:1001,:); 
will push the all the elements down a row, then use below one to write header at the end

xlswrite(filename,"your file name",sheet,'A1');

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I read on Matlab documentation that it is recommended to use textscan instead of strread so in order to better familiarize myself I tried the following:

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I read on Matlab documentation that it is recommended to use textscan instead of strread so in order to better familiarize myself I tried the following: data = textscan(fid,'%q %f','Delimiter',',');   It works with a single file but when i put it in my loop it doesnt work as i have now converted the cells into floats or i am trying to I think. The error is as follows:Conversion to cell from double is not possible.

Error in abs_spectra_SO (line 27)
     datum(:, col) = data{2}

Comment: Thank you but it worked with data = textscan(fid,'%q %q','Delimiter',',');

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, good that you figured that out!!